# DDHotKey in Xcode 7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, ddhotkey

I am developing a toolbar app where I want to have a global shortcut. I found that this capability is only possible through use of Carbon event management and fortunately I found a Cocoa wrapper (DDHotKey) for this purpose. However, I can not get it to work.
Here what I'm doing:

```
DDHotKeyCenter * center = [[DDHotKeyCenter alloc] init];
DDHotKey *key= [c registerHotKeyWithKeyCode:1 modifierFlags:NSControlKeyMask target:self action:@selector(print) object:nil];
```

After this code, key variable is nil which indicates that something went wrong. I also tried to debug and found that registerHotKeyWithKeyCode is not even called - breakpoint in its implementation is not triggered.

Need to mention that I included Carbon framework in the project settings.

DDHotKey documentation is not very comprehensive, so I stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, `DDHotKeyCenter` is meant to be accessed through the singleton method `+[DDHotKeyCenter sharedHotKeyCenter]`. Since you are trying to create a new instance using alloc/init, nil is returned.

The reason can be found in this method `+[DDHotkeyCenter allocWithZone:]`:

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return sharedHotKeyCenter;
}
```

`+allocWithZone` returns an instance variable that is only initialized in the `+sharedHotkeyCenter` method.